# Nested Select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select

I am working on a Rails application which uses `categories` for `items`.

My `category` model is self-joined so that categories can be nested:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  # Self Join (categories can have subcategories)
  has_many   :subcategories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent,        :class_name => "Category"
  ...
end
```

I have a form which allows a user to create an `item` which currently lists all categories in a select, but they are all listed together:

```
<%= f.label :category_id %>
<%= select :item, :category_id, Category.all.collect {|c| [ c.title, c.id ]} %>
```

So the select looks something like this:

```
Category1
Category2
Category3BelongsTo2
Category4BelongsTo1
```

But what I want is:

```
Category1
  - Category4BelongsTo1
Category2
  - Category3BelongsTo2
```

Is there a helper for this (which would be awesome!)?  If not, how could I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at [acts_as_nested_set](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Acts/NestedSet/ClassMethods.html), or [awesome_nested_set](http://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set)

Comment: The question is about "Nested Select in Rails" not about which solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

awesome_nested_set made this a piece of cake.

After installing, I added `lft` and `rgt` to the categories table and removed the self join.  Then rebuilt the categories table using `Category.rebuild!`.  Then the select can be easily populated like this:

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|c| "#{'-' * c.level} #{c.title}" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [grouped_options_for_select](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002242) would help you

Comment: I still want to be able to select the parent categories.